# sqlnclir.rll not unloaded upon CoUninitialize()

Tags: database, visual-c++, com, cppunit, sqlncli

We do database access via COM in a C++ coded application.

For integration testing we use CppUnit.

There in the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` we call `CoInitializeEx()` and `CoUninitialize()` respectively in order to get access to COM and stop it again after the test case.

During test case execution, **sqlncli.dll** and *sqlnclir.rll* get loaded (visible in the modules while debugging with VS2017) as we access the database.
With `CoUninitialize()`, both modules get unloaded again usually - except after `CoUninitialize()` of the 5th (coincidence?) test case, *sqlnclir.rll* remains loaded, and with that, during `CoInitializeEx()` of the next test case, **sqlncli.dll** does not get loaded anymore, eventually resulting in an access violation.
Currently, I only assume that **sqlncli.dll** does not get loaded anymore because *sqlnclir.rll* is still loaded.

So the question is: how can I either force to get *sqlnclir.rll* unloaded with `CoUninitialize()` or how do I force to load **sqlncli.dll** in the next `CoInitializeEx()` despite *sqlnclir.rll* still being loaded?

Exception gets thrown in the file atldbcli.h, function:

`HRESULT CreateCommand(_In_ const CSession& session)`

from line 7245:

`HRESULT hr = session.m_spOpenRowset->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDBCreateCommand), (void**)&spCreateCommand);`

Comment: I don't know about CppUnit but in terms of pure COM, CoInitialize(Ex) and CoUninitialize must be called for each thread involved by COM, and it's the code which creates the thread and terminates it that must call these functions. In other words, code in library or in some function somewhere must not call these functions at "random" time or when they need it. In general "CoUninitialize should be called on application shutdown" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-couninitialize#remarks